# Count for conditional probability in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, probability

Looking to use for loops to complete a conditional probability.  Here's my dataframe:

```
 make model type rating
0    f     f    c      A
1    f     f    c      B
2    f     f    s      C
3    f     f    s      A
4    f     f    s      B
5    f     f    s      B
```

I can separate the rows by 'rating', but then need to find the conditional probability for the type|rating.  Where I'm struggling is that for a rating of C, there is no 'c' type, but I need to display it still in my output.  I am looking get a count of 'type', then I can divide it by the len(rating).  Output should look like this.

```
Prob(type=c|rating=A) = 0.500000
Prob(type=s|rating=A) = 0.500000
Prob(type=c|rating=B) = 0.333333
Prob(type=s|rating=B) = 0.666667
Prob(type=c|rating=C) = 0.000000
Prob(type=s|rating=C) = 1.000000
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, now it is correct.

Comment: I saw the other problem that was posted, but I was looking to do this problem with 'for' loops and get the exact output that was posted.  Not to print out a dataframe.